# Stop running the code until it finishes the presentation of the view controller

Tags: xcode, swift3

Example:

```
if(x=y) {
   present(“XYViewController”,animated: true, completion: nil)
   x +=1
   y = 2
}
else { }
```

How can I make the operations x+=1 and y=2 run when the view controller is dismiss?

Thank you for help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: you can put inside view willDisAppear Method

Comment: If you want to run your code immediately before the dismiss is executed go with 'willDisappear' a more responsive solution is the completion handler in the dismiss function itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `View controller dismiss method`

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
  // implement your code here x+=1 and y=2
})
```